# Problemas no código em C Lista encadeada

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Estou com um problema em um código em C.
Estou tentando abrir um arquivo txt que tem nome de filme, ano , ator,...
E estou colocando os filmes em uma lista encadeada. O problema é na hora de ordenar os filmes na lista, tentei fazer pelo método da bolha (bubble sort) só que como a lista é muito grande, ao executar no Dev o programa fica executando infinitamente a função sem executar o resto que está na main (pela ineficiência da ordenação) alguém teria uma dica ou ajuda para eu aplicar no código e conseguir ordenar a lista?

Segue o código:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<conio.h>
  #define N 10000

 //wt escrita
  //rt leitura

 typedef struct Lista
 {
 char data[N];
 struct Lista *next;
 }Filmes;

 typedef struct ListaDupla 
{
char pessoa[N];
struct ListaDupla *prox;
struct ListaDupla *ant;
}DuplaLista;

  struct Lista* Insert(struct Lista *head,char data[N])
  {
    char aux3[N];
  struct Lista* tmp=((struct Lista*)malloc(sizeof(struct Lista)));
 int aux5;
 strcpy(tmp->data,data);
    tmp->next=NULL;
 if(head==NULL)
 {

    head=tmp;
    return head;
 }else{

struct Lista* aux=head;
struct Lista* aux2=head;
    while(aux->next!=NULL){
        aux=aux->next;
    }

    aux->next=tmp;



    while(aux!=NULL)
    {

        aux2=aux2->next;
        while(aux2!=NULL)
        {
     aux5=strcmp(aux->data,aux2->data);
    if(aux5>0)
    {

        strcpy(aux3,aux->data);
        strcpy(aux->data,aux2->data);
        strcpy(aux2->data,aux3);    
    }
        }
        aux=aux->next;
    }





    return head;
  } 

  // Complete this method
  }

 int main()
 {
 struct Lista* filmes=((struct Lista*)malloc(sizeof(struct Lista)));
 int opcao;
 char aux2[N];
 FILE *arq;
arq=fopen("nomes.txt","rt");
int i,a=0,b,aux;
char linha[600],nome[100];
if(arq==NULL)
{
    printf("Ocorreu um erro!");
    return 1;
}


  while(fgets(linha,700,arq))
  {



char *p=strtok(linha,",");
filmes=Insert(filmes,p);
while(filmes->next!=NULL)

{

printf(" \n Nome:%s",filmes->data);
filmes=filmes->next;
 }











    }



    fclose(arq);

  }
```

Comment: Você testou o código com poucos filmes na lista? Tipo uns 3 ou 4, para ver se funciona ou se ele "trava" também?

Comment: @Gomiero ele fica só com | piscando e não vai pra frente se eu mudar os whiles aí ele imprime os filmes mas não ordena nada fica tudo normal

Comment: Por que não ordena na inserção na lista? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/301373/inserir-nomes-ordenadamente-em-uma-lista-nao-estou-sabendo-fz-isso

Comment: Não tô vendo o bubble sort, coloca aí.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura sim na função de inserir na lista os dois whiles

Comment: Tira o primeiro `while` e conserta o código no segundo. Não adianta fazer `strcpy`; você tem que trocar os elementos de ordem. Isto é, trocar a referência apontada por `ant` e `prox` dos elementos logo anterior ao elemento a incluir, os do próprio elemento a incluir e os do elemento logo sucessor ao elemento a incluir.

Comment: Tens como postar um exemplo? @MarceloUchimura estou usando strcpy pois é string tentei fazer mudando os ponteiros e da erro

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/301373/inserir-nomes-ordenadamente-em-uma-lista-nao-estou-sabendo-fz-isso?answertab=votes#tab-top